# Create a On-Premise Gateway from Linux to Power Automate

Tags: python, power-automate, gateway, office365connectors

I'm having a lot of trouble with this question and don't really find a lot of resources with it. I have a Power Automate Flow setup (triggered by a user submitting a form) in which I would like to receive data from my on-premise (on our corporate LAN) SQL (MariaDB) instance on my RHEL. From my understanding, there are three components that I would require: (1) REST API built on my web server which would simply return the data by querying the database, (2) On-Premise Gateway on my RHEL system, and (3) A HTTP Connector in my Flow process.

Developing a simple python/php script for my REST API is quite straightforward, however, I am having a bit of difficulty building my on-premise gateway. Microsoft comes with its own free Gateway however that is only available on Windows. Would I need to set up a Windows VM and from there install the gateway or is there a better solution?

Additionally, is my approach to solve this problem correct or am I going about it wrong?